# Why in Collectors.java Class it is possible to use array indexing?

Tags: java

In collectors.java class I found this method. I cannot explain myself why you can use array indexing here. I mean this line   `(a, t) -> { a[0] = op.apply(a[0], mapper.apply(t)); },`

```
public static <T, U> Collector<T, ?, U> reducing(U identity,
                                Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper,
                                BinaryOperator<U> op) {
        return new CollectorImpl<>(
                boxSupplier(identity),
                (a, t) -> { a[0] = op.apply(a[0], mapper.apply(t)); },
                (a, b) -> { a[0] = op.apply(a[0], b[0]); return a; },
                a -> a[0], CH_NOID);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? Because `a` is an array?

Comment: but where in this class is it mentioned that a is an array . The second paramter of   CollectorImpl is  BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator,    In order to write a[0] somewhere needs to say that a is an array

Comment: Well for that you would need to find the constructor of `CollectorImpl` that this is calling. It likely takes some functional interfaces, and those functional interfaces have a single abstract method that takes some array as its first parameter.

Comment: Just tell me where it is :)

Comment: Yes I understood now that a has to be an array. But still somewhere it has to say that it is an array. Where is it ? :) To be exact it is a generic typ so it has to be mentioned somewhere

Comment: Look closely at the signature of `boxSupplier` :)

Comment: The first two arguments are `Supplier<A>` and `BiConsumer<A, T>`. So the type of `A` is determined by what the `Supplier` is going to return

Comment: Wow. For me that is really interesting. I did not know that the first Parameter can determine the types of the second parameter. Wow :) For me this is completely new or maybe I have to longer think about it

Comment: The process is called *type inference*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is it possible to use an array subscript here? Because it's an array, why wouldn't you be able to use it just like any other array?

The `Collectors#reducing` method returns a new `Collector` instance:

```
    return new CollectorImpl<>(
            boxSupplier(identity),
            (a, t) -> { a[0] = op.apply(a[0], mapper.apply(t)); },
            (a, b) -> { a[0] = op.apply(a[0], b[0]); return a; },
            a -> a[0],
            CH_NOID);
```

The signature of this `CollectorImpl` constructor is:

```
    CollectorImpl(Supplier<A> supplier,
                  BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator,
                  BinaryOperator<A> combiner,
                  Function<A,R> finisher,
                  Set<Characteristics> characteristics) {
```

The signature of `boxSupplier` is:

```
private static <T> Supplier<T[]> boxSupplier(T identity) {
    return () -> (T[]) new Object[] { identity };
}
```

which returns a `Supplier` which supplies an array (effectively wrapping the specified `identity` object lazily in an array with a single element). Consequently, type param `A` of `CollectorImpl` has to be an array of the identity's type, meaning that the second and third parameter are a `BiConsumer` of an array and a `BinaryOperator` on an array. The formal parameter `a` in the lambda's parameter list therefore is of an array type. Since it's an array, it can be used like any other array.

This is called [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html):

> Type inference is a Java compiler's ability to look at each method invocation and corresponding declaration to determine the type argument (or arguments) that make the invocation applicable. The inference algorithm determines the types of the arguments and, if available, the type that the result is being assigned, or returned. Finally, the inference algorithm tries to find the most specific type that works with all of the arguments.

You could specify the lambda parameter types explicitly to make it clearer:

```
public static <T, U>
Collector<T, ?, U> reducing(U identity,
                            Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper,
                            BinaryOperator<U> op) {
    return new CollectorImpl<>(
            boxSupplier(identity),
            (U[] a, T t) -> {a[0] = op.apply(a[0], mapper.apply(t));},
            (U[] a, U[] b) -> {a[0] = op.apply(a[0], b[0]);return a;},
            (U[] a) -> a[0],
            CH_NOID);
}
```

Or you could replace each lambda expression with an anonymous class:

```
    return new CollectorImpl<>(
            new Supplier<U[]>() {
                @Override
                public U[] get() {
                    return (U[]) new Object[]{identity};
                }
            },
            new BiConsumer<U[], T>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(final U[] a, final T t) {
                    a[0] = op.apply(a[0], mapper.apply(t));
                }
            },
            new BinaryOperator<U[]>() {
                @Override
                public U[] apply(final U[] a, final U[] b) {
                    a[0] = op.apply(a[0], b[0]);
                    return a;
                }
            },
            new Function<U[], U>() {
                @Override
                public U apply(final U[] a) {
                    return a[0];
                }
            },
            CH_NOID);
```